# Not able to refer RabbitMQ used with docker by the image name when deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file on my local machine as:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web: &my_web_app
    build: .
    command: gunicorn MyApp.wsgi --workers 3
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
  celery_worker:
    <<: *my_web_app
    command: celery -A MyApp worker --autoscale=10,1 --loglevel=info
    ports: []
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

Later, I uploaded the docker image named `web` to my docker registry named `myName/web:latest`. After that, I created a `Dockerrun.aws.json` as follows:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "cred-keeper",
    "Key": "index.docker.io/.dockercfg"
  },
  "containerDefinitions": [{
      "Authentication": {
        "Bucket": "cred-keeper",
        "Key": "index.docker.io/.dockercfg"
      },
      "command": [
        "celery",
        "-A",
        "MyApp",
        "worker",
        "--autoscale=10,1",
        "--loglevel=info"
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "image": "myName/web:latest",
      "name": "celery_worker",
      "memory": 175
    },
    {
      "essential": true,
      "image": "rabbitmq:management",
      "name": "rabbitmq",
      "memory": 175,
      "portMappings": [{
        "containerPort": 5672,
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "hostPort": 5672
      }]
    },
    {
      "Authentication": {
        "Bucket": "cred-keeper",
        "Key": "index.docker.io/.dockercfg"
      },
      "command": [
        "gunicorn",
        "MyApp.wsgi",
        "--workers",
        "4"
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "image": "myName/web:latest",
      "memory": 256,
      "name": "web",
      "portMappings": [{
        "containerPort": 8000,
        "hostPort": 80
      }]
    }
  ],
  "family": "",
  "volumes": []
}
```

The image named `web` is a Django (Python's web framework) app, where I used to access my RabbitMQ container using a URL that used the container name in the app like `amqp://rabbitmq:5672` and it used to work perfectly fine when I used to run it on my local machine.

But, when I deployed it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using the `Dockerrun.aws.json`, I got an error in my celery container's logs like `[2020-07-24 08:29:51,709: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@rabbitmq:5672//: failed to resolve broker hostname`.

Why am I not able to access RabbitMQ on AWS by the name of the container's image in the URL like it was working on my local machine? How should I access the RabbitMQ container deployed on AWS instance if not by using `amqp://rabbitmq:5672` as the URL on my Django web app?

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add, in the `docker-compose.yml`, under `web` section, something like this?:

```
links:
  - rabbitmq
```

And in `Dockerrun.aws.json`, under `celery_worker` and `web` you will have to add:

```
"links": [
   "rabbitmq"
]
```